# Removing duplicate lines with different columns

Tags: shell, awk, duplicates, rows

I have a file which looks like follows:

```
  ENSG00000197111:I12 0
  ENSG00000197111:I12 1
 ENSG00000197111:I13 0
 ENSG00000197111:I18 0
 ENSG00000197111:I2 0
 ENSG00000197111:I3 0
 ENSG00000197111:I4 0
 ENSG00000197111:I5 0
 ENSG00000197111:I5 1
```

I have some lines that are duplicated but I cannot remove by sort -u because the second column has different values for them (1 or 0). How do I remove such duplicates by keeping the lines with second column as 1 such that the file will be

```
 ENSG00000197111:I12 1
 ENSG00000197111:I13 0
 ENSG00000197111:I18 0
 ENSG00000197111:I2 0
 ENSG00000197111:I3 0
 ENSG00000197111:I4 0
 ENSG00000197111:I5 1
```

Comment: when you use `-u` with `-t: -k1,1` what happens? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `awk` and `or` operator, if the order isn't mandatory

```
awk '{d[$1]=d[$1] || $2}END{for(k in d) print k, d[k]}' file
```

you get

```
ENSG00000197111:I2 0
ENSG00000197111:I3 0
ENSG00000197111:I4 0
ENSG00000197111:I5 1
ENSG00000197111:I12 1
ENSG00000197111:I13 0
ENSG00000197111:I18 0
```

**Edit, only `sort` solution**

You can use `sort` with a double pass, example

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2r file | sort -u -k1,1
```

you get,

```
ENSG00000197111:I12 1
ENSG00000197111:I13 0
ENSG00000197111:I18 0
ENSG00000197111:I2 0
ENSG00000197111:I3 0
ENSG00000197111:I4 0
ENSG00000197111:I5 1
```